# General Solution by Method of Elimination

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following system :

$(D^2+1)[x]-2D[y]=2t$ 
$(2D-1)[x]+(D-2)[y]=7$

Omitting all the work, I have solved it by reducing it to an equivalent triangular system, first for y and again for x, arriving at the following general solutions :

For y : 
$y(t) = c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}+c_3e^{-2t}-t-1$ 
$x(t) = c_1e^t-c_2e^{-t}-\frac{4}{5}c_3e^{-2t}+2t-2$

For x : 
$x(t) = c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}+c_3e^{-2t}+2t-2$ 
$y(t) = c_1e^t-c_2e^{-t}-\frac{5}{4}c_3e^{-2t}-t-1$

It is my understanding that the solutions should be equivalent regardless of which variable I eliminate, but there are some variations between the signs and coefficients of my arbitrary constants $c_n (n = 1,2,3)$ e.g. $c_3e^{-2t}$ and $-\frac{5}{4}c_3e^{-2t}$ for $y(t)$.

Is this to be expected and would the signs and coefficients simply be "absorbed" into their respective arbitrary constants? i.e. Are these general solutions in fact equal?

**Update**

I reduce the system to the following equivalent triangular system :

$[D^3+2D^2-D-2]y = 2t+3$ (1)
$5x+[-2D^2-5D+2]y = 8t-7$ (2)

From (1) I find the solution $y(t) = c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}+c_3e^{-2t}-t-1$ which I then substitute into (2) and solve for $x(t) = c_1e^t-c_2e^{-t}-\frac{4}{5}c_3e^{-2t}+2t-2$

Comment: Is the first part written correctly?

Comment: @Moo Double checked and yes, it is written the same way in my study material.

Comment: I had a sign error. You can absorb those constant and just call them another constant, so $-c_2$ can be changed to $c_2$, for example. Same with the other constants. Recall, even if you don't do that, you are still not done. You have to substitute $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ into the DE and solve for the constants to produce the correct solution - there are restrictions. You can even try it with both your solutions as-is or you can absorb the constants. I got something slightly different than you, bt I believe they are close enough.

Comment: Ah, that's true. Thanks! I think I lost sight of that chasing a red herring ... I'll substitute and solve for the constants and see from there. May I ask what you got?

Comment: $x(t) = e^t + 2 t - 2, y(t) = e^t - t - 1$. You can substitute them back in and verify they solve the system.

Comment: Interesting - When you substitute and solve for the homogeneous equation of x(t) or y(t) does your complimentary function also resemble $(D^3+2D^2-D-2)x=0$?

Comment: Ah, just saw your comment - no worries. Later I'll rework the problem from scratch with your comments in mind and post my findings. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: That looks what like I'm "expecting" to find. However, I just ran through the problem again and I'm still having trouble with the coefficient on $c_3$. I've updated the original post above with the steps I am taking. Could you perhaps glance over it?

Comment: For $x(t)$, I get $(D^3 + 2 D^2 - D - 2)x = -4 t + 2$ and for $y(t)$, I am getting $(D^3 + 2 D^2 - D - 2)y = 2 t + 3$, which leads to what I show. Try it and see what you get.

Comment: Right, this correlates with my original approach of solving the system twice, once for $x(t)$ and then for $y(t)$. The problem arises when I try to take the shortcut of substituting one solution into the triangular system. I'll try again after some sleep - a fresh brain should help. BTW - I attempted to move this to a chat, as the site is warning me against extended discussions in the comments, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points ...

Comment: @Moo As I stated in my comment to the answer below, it makes sense to me now. Just want to thank you once again for your assistance and working through the problem for/with me. It was very helpful. I'd throw some points your way if I could ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you have a problem. Your first solution is:
$$\begin{align} & y(t)=c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}+c_3e^{-2t}-t-1 \\
& x(t)=c_1e^t-c_2e^{-t}-\frac45c_3e^{-2t}+2t-2\end{align}$$
And your second is:
$$\begin{align} & x(t)=d_1e^t+d_2e^{-t}+d_3e^{-2t}+2t-2 \\
& y(t)=d_1e^t-d_2e^{-t}-\frac54d_3e^{-2t}-t-1\end{align}$$
And they are identical given $d_1=c_1$, $d_2=-c_2$, and $d_3=-\frac45c_3$.

Comment: I think my problem is that I was questioning the validity of this and whether it was allowed i.e. it wasn't quite "clicking" with me, if that makes sense. But looking over it with fresh eyes I'm satisfied. Thanks you for your assistance!